# Opening Selected URL in default browser(Chrome) in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel File with approx 1200 URL's.

I have a macro that will open these URL's in single shot , but I realize that this will make system slow and probably might not be possible too.

So I thought to make some changes in script to open URL's only in selected cells ( lets say 20) , for e.g. if I select Cell A1:A20 and run macro , it should open them in my default browser ,  once I am done with my operation , I will select next 20 and run macro again.

Here is my Macro, kindly let me know how I can I change to to work only on selected cells

```
Sub Open_Hyperlinks()
    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, "A").Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cells are already entered as hyperlinks use this:

```
Sub Open_SelectedHyperlinks()
    Dim c As Range
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then _
            c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

Else, this will follow all cells, even if they are not entered as hyperlinks:

```
Sub Open_SelectedTextlinks()
    Dim c As Range

    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, _
                Address:="http://" & c.Value 'Depending on the content of your cell, remove the "http://" & part
        End If
        c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
    Next
End Sub
```